# How to add a delay between processes in a single job?

Tags: laravel

Lets say I have this job:

```
class DeleteInstagramImage implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public  $tries  =  2;

    public function handle()
    {
        // do some code

        if ($condtion) {
          // wait for some given time and try again
        }
    }
}
```

As I understand `$tries  =  2` This will let the job to be processed , **2 times** then It will fail if error was found.

#### Q: How to add a delay between the processes in this job? so that if condition is met, It will wait before entering the second try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sleep` option will delay the time in between the worker processing jobs.

> When jobs are available on the queue, the worker will keep processing jobs with no delay in between them. However, the sleep option determines how long (in seconds) the worker will "sleep" if there are no new jobs available. While sleeping, the worker will not process any new jobs - the jobs will be processed after the worker wakes up again.

If you're running redis, there is the `block_for` option which will delay polling of the redis database.

> When using the Redis queue, you may use the block_for configuration option to specify how long the driver should wait for a job to become available before iterating through the worker loop and re-polling the Redis database.

Lastly, to delay the thread execution, use [usleep](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usleep.php):

```
public function handle()
{
    // do some code

    if ($condtion) {
      usleep(50000); // sleep for half a second.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only reliable solution I can think of is to use `$tries = 1` and to dispatch the same job again if the condition matches - but as delayed job (or to delay it in the first place):

```
DeleteInstagramImage::dispatch($this->image)
    ->delay(now()->addMinutes(1));
```

But be aware this is basically an endless loop and you will also need an exit-strategy. For example you could store an execution counter in the cache which is removed after 30 minutes. Something like `Cache::put("instagram-img-deletion-{$this->image->id}", $tries, now()->addMinutes(30))` with checking the tries beforehand.